# Accessing jsonb column and attributes from a Rails 5 Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, jsonb

I'm having a strange issue when I try to create a scope for one on my models that is accessing something in jsonb. The query looks fine by me but it seems to not find any records even though I'm pretty sure they exist!

After reading [postgresql docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html) the following code should work.

Can anyone spot the problem?

```
scope :financing_offer_eq, ->(field, value) do
  where(
    "cars.financing_offer->>:field = :value",
    field: field,
    value: value
  )
end
```

**Output**

```
Car.financing_offer_eq(:down_payment, '10000')
  Car Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "cars".* FROM "cars" WHERE (cars.financing_offer->>'down_payment' = '10000')
=> []
```

**Here is a sample car**

```
[132] pry(main)> Car.find(15).financing_offer
  Car Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "cars".* FROM "cars" WHERE "cars"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> {"amount_of_loan"=>"10000", "total_amount"=>"10000", "total_cost"=>"10000", "borrowing_rate"=>"1.2", "annual_percentage_rate"=>"1.2", "monthly_payment"=>"1.2", "down_payment"=>"10000"}

#<Car:0x007fea76ebf358
 id: 15,
 ...
 removed irrelevant attributes
 ...
 financing_offer: {"amount_of_loan"=>"10000", "total_amount"=>"10000", "total_cost"=>"10000", "borrowing_rate"=>"1.2", "annual_percentage_rate"=>"1.2", "monthly_payment"=>"1.2", "down_payment"=>"10000"}>
```

**Also tried running queries in the console:**

```
Car.where("financing_offer ->>'{down_payment}' = '10000'")
  Car Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "cars".* FROM "cars" WHERE (financing_offer ->>'{down_payment}' = '10000')
=> []

Car.where("financing_offer ->> 'down_payment' = :value", value: '10000')
  Car Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "cars".* FROM "cars" WHERE (financing_offer ->> 'down_payment' = '10000')
=> []

Car.where("financing_offer ->> 'down_payment'= '10000'")
  Car Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "cars".* FROM "cars" WHERE (financing_offer->>'down_payment'= '10000')
=> []

Car.where('financing_offer @> ?', {down_payment: '10000'}.to_json)
  Car Load (1.9ms)  SELECT "cars".* FROM "cars" WHERE (financing_offer @> '{"down_payment":"10000"}')
=> []
```

If it makes any difference I'm using [Storext](https://github.com/G5/storext) gem for AR mapping, Rails 5, postgresql 9.4.5. It's also not working if I don't use storext or I use another mapping gem [jsonb_accessor](https://github.com/devmynd/jsonb_accessor)

Comment: Could you post the data of some records which should be selected by this query?

Comment: I posted a car, but it has a lot of irrelevant attributes which I removed. Not sure how that helps :)

Comment: I just wanted to see whether the values were json-integer types or just plain strings. Thanks!

Comment: You are right! Sorry. All of them are Strings

Answer (score 1):

I created a repo verified your scope works.

https://github.com/JuanitoFatas/rails-5-jsonb/commit/fb60e12bda07504ad71efe5c78aa1918661d353c

Maybe try these:

- Search jsonb issue on gems GitHub page that may affects this
- restart rails console
- recreate database (`rails db:drop db:create db:migrate`)
- restart your computer

Comment: Nice! I'm saving json to that store. That's why I use something like storext. It's working for `Car.create(financing_offer: {"down_payment" => "1000"})` but not for `Car.create(financing_offer: {"down_payment" => "1000"}.to_json)`

Comment: Thank you. I'm almost sure that storext is causing this. I've opened an issue here: https://github.com/G5/storext/issues/31 if you want to follow-up or replicate the issue in your dummy app.